# AHK: Open folder or activate it if already opened

Tags: windows, batch, autohotkey

I'm using [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and try to do this:

- Open download folder (`Q:\Down` in my case) or activate it if already opened (subfolders don't count, for example still open `Q:\Down` if I opened `Q:\Down\phvideos` already)

Script I'm using

```
Run "Q:\Down"
```

or

```
Run % "explorer /expand, Q:\Down\"
```

Both of them can open such a folder, but activate it again will open a duplicate window in explorer.

Is there any command that opens unique folder, or detects if given folder path exists in an opened explorer window?

Comment: The first example is exactly what I use to do this for a local folder. I don't use quotes on either end but I wouldn't expect that to matter. It may be different for folders that are on the same drive where Windows is installed but that would also be surprising. `Run` should work the same way the shell's Run command works.

Comment: It works, wtf I was doing by searching the Internet for 3 hours, I already got the solution already lol....dunno why it didn't work when I test it the first time, thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option

**"[Display the full path in the title bar](https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/how-to-display-full-path-of-files-and-folders.html)"** enabled,

[image]you can use

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 3
If WinExist("Q:\Down ahk_class CabinetWClass")
    WinActivate
else
    Run % "explorer /expand, Q:\Down\"
```

Otherwise you can try this:

```
Run_explorer("Q:\Down")

Run_explorer(path) {
    If InStr(explorer_list(), path)
    {
        Loop, Parse, % explorer_list(), `n
        {
            If InStr(A_LoopField, path)
            {
                ID := StrSplit(A_LoopField,"_").1
                WinActivate, ahk_id %ID%
                    break
            }
        }
    }
    else
        Run % path
}

explorer_list() {
    ; Get ID + fullpath of all opened explorer windows:
    If WinExist("ahk_class CabinetWClass") ; explorer
    {
        list := ""
        ; https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=28751#p28751
        for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
        {
            try explorer_path := window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
            If (explorer_path = "")
                continue
            WinGet, ID, ID, % explorer_path
            list .= ID "_" explorer_path ? ID "_" explorer_path "`n" : "" 
        }
        list := trim(list, "`n")
        return list
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already forgot this question lol, this is my script rn, to help future users

```
global DOWNLOAD_FOLDER := "K:\Down"
; win + q   Open Down
#q::
{
    downWinTitle := "Down ahk_class CabinetWClass"
    WinGet explorerHwnd, ID, % downWinTitle
    path := GetExplorerPath(explorerHwnd)
    if(!explorerHwnd || path != DOWNLOAD_FOLDER){
        Run % "explorer /expand, " . DOWNLOAD_FOLDER
        WinWait % downWinTitle
        WinGet explorerHwnd, ID, % downWinTitle
    }
    WinActivate % "ahk_id " . explorerHwnd
    Return
}
```